# How was this changed to get $r_p$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ \frac{G \,m_p \,m_{*}}{r_p^2} =\frac{m_p\,v_p^2}{r_p}$$

$$ r_p =\frac{G\,m_{*}}{v_p^2}$$

([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiUsS.png))

Can someone help me with the steps to get the equation like this? I want to know the process of how they changed the equation for it to equal $r_p$.

Comment: Write down the equation *here*. That link looks pretty suspicious...Showing some self work won't hurt, too.

Comment: I want to know how he cancelled out and rearranged the top equation to get rp to equal g mstar / Vp^2

Comment: Looks like a physics question involving planet surrounding stars on a circular orbit with radius $r_p$ at speed $v_p$?

Comment: Yes frenzy it is that, but I'm not looking at that aspect I'm just confused to how he got the equation to be like that.

Comment: It's very elementary algebra ! Cancel $r_p$ and $m_p$...

Comment: Jean. I have gotten up to that step so far but I'm unsure of how he go the V little p ^2 on the bottom etc

Comment: @LiamB Multiply both sides of the first equation by $r_p^2$. Which side has $r_p$ left? Where is $v_p^2$, is it on the same side? If so, do you now know why the $v_p^2$ is now on the bottom in equation 2?

Comment: Thank you frenzy. I didn't really get what you said but then I was able to use a part of what you said to get it. What I did first was cancel the m_p then the r_p^2 so it would be G M_* / r_p = V_p^2 then I times both sides by r_p then dividing both sides by V_p^2

Comment: Thank you guys and sorry for bad formating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first expression *seems* to be:

$$\frac{Gm_pm_*}{r_p^2}=\frac{m_pv_p^2}{r_p}$$

Multiply both sides by $\;r_p^2\;$ and also divide both sides by $\;m_p\;$ and get

$$Gm_*=r_pv_p^2\;\;\implies\;\;r_p=\frac{Gm_*}{v_p^2}$$

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how you removed the ^2 from the r_p

Comment: When you multiplied *the right* side by $\;r_p^2\;$ you got $$\frac{r_p^2\cdot m_p\cdot v_p^2}{r_p}=r_pm_pv_p^2$$ because it is just like $\;\frac{a^2}a=a\;$ ...This seems to be some calculation with gravity, mass, radius and stuff. This looks like high school physics. It could help to know what is your mathematics level.